# Series Help: $\sum_{n>0}\frac{1}{n^{1+|\sin n|}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does the series $ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1 + |\sin(n)|}} $ converge or diverge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270064/does-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n1-sinn-conve)

I am having a very hard time with the following series: 
$$\sum_{n>0}\frac{1}{n^{1+|\sin n|}}$$
I don't even have clues for guessing its character. Does it converge or not?

Of course the heart of the problem is the structure of the set

$$X=\{|\sin n|: \, n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$

In fact $x=0$ is not in the limit class of $X$, otherwise we'd be able to find a convergent subsequence of $|\sin n|$ (and so the series would diverge); however zero is an accumulation point of $X$, so it is hopeless to try to compare our series with

$$\sum_{n>0}\frac{1}{n^{1+\varepsilon}}$$

for any fixed ε. Any ideas?

Comment: This problem has had an illustrious history here on Math StackExchange.