# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+\left|{\cos n}\right|}}$ - convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1+\left|{\cos n}\right|}}$  convergent?

Yes because $|\cos n|>0$  and   $\frac{1}{n^ \alpha}$ is convergent for $\alpha>1$.

Is this a good way?

Comment: So, $\sum 1/ n^{1+1/n}$ converges?

Comment: No, this is not a good way. (And the question was already asked on the site.)

Comment: Tastes a lot like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270064/does-the-series-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n1-sinn-conve

Comment: In order to apply Comparison directly, one would have to show that $|\cos n|\gt \beta$ for some *fixed* positive $\beta$. Unfortunately this is not true.

Comment: your alpha is not constant, so your series is not a p-series of Riemann

Comment: @Imago what you're saying is wrong.

Comment: @ LeGrandDODOM: Ah, ty, I have just your post with the link and it really seems to be not that trivial. 
I had realized that you had a non constant alpha, but didn't think it through, if that would turn into a bigger problem.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Thanks, this is the question I had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

To be less subtle, you would need $|\cos n|\ge\alpha>0$ for some constant $\alpha$. Good luck with that!! :)

@DavidMitra's example is one of my favorites. Yes, $1+1/n\to 1$, but note that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{n^{1+1/n}}}{\frac 1n}= 1,$$
so the limit comparison test says that the given series diverges.

Comment: I disagree. One does not *need* such condition to have a convergent series. It is a sufficient condition, not a necessary one.

Comment: Of course, @Jack, but that was not the reasoning the OP suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. To give a rigorous proof, you have to quantify *how often* $|\cos n|$ is close to zero. This depends on the irrationality measure of $\pi$. Since $\{n\pmod{\pi}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an equidistributed sequence, it is expected that $|\cos n|$ is, *in average*, $\frac{2}{\pi}$, giving a convergent series. However, this is not the case, as shown by the duplicate question's answers.