# How to investigate the $\limsup$, the $\liminf$, the $\sup$, and especially the $\inf$ of the sequence $(\sqrt[n]{|\sin{n}|})_{n=1}^{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry, radicals, supremum-and-infimum

How to investigate the $\limsup$, the $\liminf$, the $\sup$, and **especially** the $\inf$ of the sequence $(\sqrt[n]{|\sin{n}|})_{n=1}^{\infty}$?

**Edit:** The limit of this sequence is already investigated years ago in this post: [Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{|\sin n|}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48035/275935). So the $\limsup$, the $\liminf$, and the $\sup$ are clearly 1. Sorry for did not search wisely.

Comment: Do you have any guesses at least? Something to show you've thought about the problem before posting it?

Comment: @Clayton: I guess 0 and 1 will probably be the answers but I have no idea how to prove it after thinking a week (and yeah that is probably not long enough). :(

Comment: Where does this problem comes from?

Comment: @Surb: It is an exercise appeared in an undergraduate analysis course reader edited by a math professor (or professors) in Taiwan...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is far from being trivial.

The sequence given by $a_n=e^{in}$ is dense in the unit circle since $\pi$ is an irrational number. By considering $\text{Im}(a_n)$, we get that the sequence given by $b_n=\sin(n)$ is dense in the interval $[-1,1]$.

However, that is not enough to prove that the wanted $\sup,\inf,\liminf,\limsup$ are $1,0,0,1$.

By Lagrange's theorem there is an infinite number of rational numbers $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ such that:

$$ \left| \pi-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\right| \leq \frac{1}{q_n^2} $$
holds, and in such a case:
$$ \left|\sin(p_n)\right|\leq \frac{1}{q_n}, $$
but that is not enough to ensure that $\left|\sin(p_n)\right|^{\frac{1}{p_n}}$ is arbitrarily close to zero.

The problem strongly depends on the irrationality measure of $\pi$. Since $\pi$ [has a finite irrationality measure](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=rm&paperid=9175&option_lang=eng) (it is conjectured to be $2$, but until today no one has proved something better than $7.6$) our $\inf$ is indeed a minimum and it is strictly greater than zero.

Comment: "However, that is not enough to prove that the wanted sup,inf,lim inf,lim sup are 0,1,0,1."  Jack, how is the sup $0$ and the inf $1$ ()?  Surely, you meant to write the transposition.  ;-)) -Mark

Answer (score 2):

I will show that
$\sqrt[n]{|\sin(n)|}
\to 1
$
as
$n \to \infty
$.

Since this depends on
how close $n$ can be to
$\pi$, 
what is useful here is
the irrationality measure of
$\pi$.

It turns out that
there is a value $v > 0$
such that,
for any rational approximation
$\frac{p}{q}$
to $\pi$,
$\big|\pi- \frac{p}{q}\big|
>\frac1{q^{v}}
$.
$v = 20$ will work.

Here is one article
that shows this:
https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195511637

Therefore,
$|n-m\pi|
=m|\frac{n}{m}-\pi|
> m\frac1{m^{v}}
=\frac1{m^{v-1}}
$.

Now,
we need a bound relating to $n$,
not $m$.

Since
we can choose
$|n-m\pi|
< \pi
$,
$|m\pi|
=|n-(n-m\pi)|
\le |n|+|n-m\pi|
$,
or
$|n| 
\ge |m\pi|
$,
so
$\frac1{|n|}
\le \frac1{|m\pi|}
$,
or
$\frac1{|m|}
\ge \frac{\pi}{|n|}
$.

Therefore,
$|n-m\pi|
>\frac1{m^{v-1}}
\ge\frac{\pi^{v-1}}{n^{v-1}}
$.

Since
$\sin(n)
=\sin(n-m\pi)
$,
and,
for
$|x| < \frac{pi}{2}$,
$|sin(x)|
\ge \frac{2x}{\pi}
$,
$|\sin(n)|
=|\sin(n-m\pi)|
> |\frac{2(n-m\pi)}{\pi|}
\ge |\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\pi^{v-1}}{n^{v-1}}|
= |\frac{2\pi^{v-2}}{n^{v-1}}|
$.

Now,
we finally get to the conclusion.

From this,
$\sqrt[n]{|\sin(n)|}
\ge \sqrt[n]{|\frac{2\pi^{v-2}}{n^{v-1}}|}
=|\frac{(2\pi^{v-2})^{1/n}}{n^{(v-1)/n}}|
$.
But,
both
$a^{1/n} \to 1$
and
$n^{1/n} \to 1$
as 
$n \to \infty$.

Therefore
$\sqrt[n]{|\sin(n)|}
\to 1
$
as
$n \to \infty
$.

Note:
I am sure this has been done before.

Comment: So the finite irrationality measure solves the $\sup$ and $\limsup$, but what about the $\inf$ and $\liminf$?

Comment: This shows that $\sqrt[n]{|\sin(n)|}\to 1$ for a *subsequence*, right? Hence this shows that sup and limsup are $1$ and says nothing about the (possibly nonexistent) limit.

Comment: No. The paper I linked says that it is true for *all* approximations with large enough denominators.

Answer (score -1):

Well first of all try to calculate the absolute value of |sinn|. Since the sine function is defined on (-1;1) the absolute value of |sinn|<1. Then the order of the root, as it tends to infinity the root will get smaller and smaller so basically it will tend to 0. Try to figure out yourself the interval of definition of the function and from there you'll find the sup, inf etc. *My first post here on the math section, don't kill me* Hope I helped.

Comment: You're missing the difficulty. First, if $0<c<1$, $\sqrt[n]{c} \to 1$, so by your argument, it should converge to 1, not to 0. But $\sin(n)$ can get as close as we want to $0$, so it's possible that for some n, $\sqrt[n]{\sin(n)}$ is as close as we want to 0. It depend on "the speed" of approximation of $k\pi$ by an integer