# Convergence of a Taylor series expansion involving $\tan^{-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

Taylor series expansion of $\tan^{-1}\left(\cfrac{\sin(\theta)+r\cos(\phi)}{\cos(\theta)+r\sin(\phi)}\right)$ around $r=0$ is as follows:

$$\begin{align}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(\theta)+r\cos(\phi)}{\cos(\theta)+r\sin(\phi)}\right)={} &\theta+r\cos(\psi)-\frac{r^2}{2} \sin(2\psi)-\frac{r^3}{3}\cos(3\psi)+\frac{r^4}{4}\sin(4\psi)\\
&{}+\frac{r^5}{5}\cos(5\psi)-\frac{r^6}{6}\sin(6\psi)-\frac{r^7}{7}\cos(7\psi)+\frac{r^8}{8}\sin(8\psi)+\cdots\\
\end{align}\tag{1}$$
where $\psi\equiv\theta+\phi$.

I am interested in the radius of convergence of this series for $\psi\in[0,2\pi]$.  Clearly, it converges for $|r|<1$: since $\sin x\in[-1,1]$ and $\cos x\in [-1,1]$ we can replace the trigonometric functions by their upper and lower bounds to yield the following upper and lower bounds for the RHS of (1): $\theta\pm\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{r^i}{i}=\theta\pm\log(1-r)$.  However, I am wondering what happens to the series when $|r|\geq1$. Any hints/tips/ideas on how to evaluate this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

For $|r|>1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(-1)^nr^{2n}\sin(2n\psi)}{2n}\right|}&=r^2\,\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{\sin(2n\psi)}{2n}\right|}\\\\
&=r^2\\\\
&>1
\end{align}$$

with an analogous result for the odd terms of the series.

For $r=1$, the series convergence is guaranteed using [Leibniz's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test).

For $r=-1$, the series convergence is guaranteed for $\psi \ne 0$ by [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Statement)

Comment: Very nice answer.  Thank you for reminding me about the $n$-th root test.  The limit superior follows from the answers [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48035/calculate-lim-n-to-infty-sqrtn-sin-n) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460048/how-to-investigate-the-limsup-the-liminf-the-sup-and-especially-the?rq=1) -- both very interesting posts in their own right.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure. -Mark

Answer (score 0):

*Since Dr. MV already answered the question for $|r|>1$, this is probably too long for a comment.*

I may be wrong but it seems to me that the Taylor series expansion around $r=0$ is 
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(\theta)+r\sin(\phi)}{\cos(\theta)+r\cos(\phi)}\right)=\theta+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin\left(n(\theta-\phi)\right)\,r^n=\theta+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}\sin\left(n\psi\right)\,r^n$$ with $\color{red}{\psi=\theta-\phi}$.

Consider $\theta=\phi$ in the expression and in the one you propose.

Comment: Ooops.  I actually had mis-typed the LHS of (1) in transcription from when I was working this out by hand.  The updated LHS is correct, and consistent with the RHS.  Sorry!

Comment: @M.B.M. So, fix it in the the first place too.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks for pointing that out.  Done.